# Problems using phpMyAdmin from iPhone

Tags: iphone, phpmyadmin

I do a lot of web stuff from my phone and sometimes I need to go in to a database using phpMyAdmin to change some things.

The problem I'm having is with the Run SQL tool. From the iPhone I'm not able to double-tap the text area to Paste the command. Even typing everything in proves difficult. It seems to be an issue with the line numbers.

I know I know I shouldn't even be doing that kind of work via my iPhone, phpMyAdmin isn't exactly designed for mobile usage, but I do. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try MySQL Quick Admin http://www.fusionswift.com/mysql-quick-admin/

"..is a essentially a light weight version of PHPMyAdmin.."

Comment: it was useful for you?